# I want to rename Maven project and keep its Subversion history

Tags: netbeans, maven

I am using NetBeans 6.9 and trying to rename Maven Project name and keep its Subversion history.

Please tell me if there is any possible way to rename it.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `<name>` or `<artifactId>` element in `pom.xml` - your Subversion history will be unaffected.

Similarly, Subversion will allow you to [rename a folder](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re18.html) in the repository, preserving history.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a build tool, and maybe more, but not a source code management system or version control system. Keeping a change history of your project would rather be the job of something like Subversion or Git.
Create a Git repository, commit your stuff, change names afterwards.