# How to rename maven modules?

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, module, rename

I have small project in which there are three modules:

```
<modules>
        <module>ejb</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>ear</module>
</modules>
```

I wish to rename these maven modules. First thing i tried was, just rename module names pom.xml of parent. e.g.

```
<modules>
        <module>ejb-ext</module>
        <module>web-ext</module>
        <module>ear-ext</module>
</modules>
```

When I tried to compile the project, maven complained that child modules (e.g. ejb-ext) do not exists.

I use eclipse IDE, then i renamed every module using eclipse menu *refactor -> rename*. But due to this now SVN shows me that old modules `ejb`, `web` and `ear` are deleted, and there are new modules added `ejb-ext`, `web-ext` and `ear-ex`t.

Is there any way to rename modules, without loosing their SVN history? I referred following thread, but it didnt help:

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308048/i-want-to-rename-maven-project-and-keep-its-subversion-history)
[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000371/renaming-module-in-maven-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue in two steps approach:

1) First I modified my poms to mention new module names. Then checked in the code. Of-course it failed with error that child modules (e.g. ejb-ext) do not exists.

2) In second step I used SVN rename option to rename child modules. SVN rename automatically holds the history. And then I checked in the code to resolve build issues.
I renamed child module using Eclipse SVN repositories view. Here you can simple right click on child modules and rename them using option "rename/move".

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 6):

Maven modules names should refer to a directory, so you *have* to rename the directory.

SVN should be able to know that the newly created directories come from another existing one that has just been deleted. There is no such "MOVE" or "RENAME" operation per se, but the link is made through a "from" attribute linked to the copy operation (in fact, the move is a copy-with-from+delete).

So if eclipse does its work correctly, you won't loose any history.

Comment: I think you are right. Because when right click on new renamed maven modules and check their SVN history, I see old revisions. Let me try it this way. I will update you soon.

Comment: you are right. If found referrence: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-subversion/

Comment: Good. Just be careful, before committing a move, to check that the IDE has correctly handled it, and did not make a simple delete + copy without keeping a reference to the original path. You can easily check this by issuing for instance a _svn status_ command in the command line. At least recent versions of SVN will indicate if there is a link (something like _abc moved from xyz_).

Comment: svn status says that old modules are deleted. But for new modules there is no svn status. What does it mean? And when I check SVN history in eclipse, it shows me whole history. I am just confiused if I shall check in or not :O